# Numpy with Python's Decimal arguments

Tags: python, numpy, decimal

I have a little problem. 
In my program, in Python 3.3, I made a list of decimal values (x):

```
  [Decimal('646'), Decimal('651'), Decimal('657')]
```

And I want to know the mean value using Numpy.

So I wrote:

```
  tempArray = numpy.array(x, dtype=np.dtype(decimal.Decimal))
```

But I got the error:

```
  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Decimals instead of floats?

Comment: You wrote "*I want to know the mean value*", and yet you have `tempArray = numpy.array(...)` - and `numpy.mean` is not used anywhere in this OP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works just fine for me on Python 2.7

```
import numpy
from decimal import Decimal

x = [Decimal('646'), Decimal('651'), Decimal('657')]
tempArray = numpy.array(x, dtype=numpy.dtype(Decimal))
print numpy.mean(tempArray)
```

Comment: Hmm, Matt, this code does not run in my Python 3.3.  There is the same error, which I have mentioned above:   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

Comment: What if you just get rid of the dtype=numpy.dtype(Decimal) and do 

tempArray = numpy.array(x)

Comment: Now there is the same error.  The only change in my code in compare to Yours is print function, which has parentheses: print (numpy.mean(tempArray)), because of Python 3 standard. And now, when I have got rid dtype=numpy.dtype(Decimal) problem is the same.

Comment: Looks like numpy has no notion of Decimal and is just making it a generic object. If you do numpy.array(x, dtype=float) it should work

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to use Numpy? This can be done easily with

```
>>> sum(x)/len(x)
Decimal('651.3333333333333333333333333')
```

That said, I was able to do

```
>>> np.array(x).mean()
Decimal('651.3333333333333333333333333')
```